# Counting warnings from MSBuild task

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I have the following msbuild goop :

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(MySLN)" Targets="Build" />
<!--count all warning and fail if > 20-->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(BuildFolder)"
  IgnoreExitCode="true"
  Command="$(POWERSHELL) -command $host.SetShouldExit(([xml](get-content '$(LogsFolder)productbuild-results.xml')).SelectNodes('//warning').count)"
>
  <Output PropertyName="BuildSLNWarningCount" TaskParameter="ExitCode" />
</Exec>
```

In theory this will count the number of warnings in the log file so I can abort the build if there are too many (>20 in our case).

However, I dont know how to get the MSBuild task to output a log file - seperate from the log file that is produced from the main MSBuild file that this task is run by. Also, I still need the main log file to contain the full build details as it's used by CCnet.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Awe gee.  Can no-one answer this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be writing a custom MSBuild task which does everything you need, and call that in your build script. I blogged an example [here](http://programatealgo.blogspot.com/2011/03/msbuild-how-to-develop-custom-build.html). My task has a very different intent from yours, but you should get the main concepts about writing a custom task.

**Update**: Another posibility is using the `Exec` task to call MSBuild redirecting its output to a file:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(BuildFolder)"
  IgnoreExitCode="true"
  Command="$(MSBuildDirectory)msbuild params > output_file.txt"
>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid that.  But I dont think that will help anyway as I need the output warnings the MSBuild task and unless I write my own MSBuild task I cant see how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: You could call the MSBuild task from your custom task and capture its output. The way I see it, there's no limit to what you can do with a custom task

Comment: But then Im back to my original problem - how do I capture the output to a file?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [`BuildManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.execution.buildmanager.aspx) class...
The [BeginBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.execution.buildmanager.beginbuild.aspx) method on the BuildManager allows you to pass in a set of [BuildParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.execution.buildparameters.aspx) which includes a Loggers property. In the Logger you can capture anything MSBUILD outputs and count etc.